# property в GNU Compiler Collection

Tags: c++, gcc

Есть ли в GCC аналог  microsoft'овских property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx
Кажется не так давно натыкался на статью. Или это мне приснилось.

Comment: Есть схема работы с атрибутами, смотрите `__attribute__ ((..))`

Comment: Можно сделать свой аналог на шаблонах/макросах...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, AFAIK в gcc ничего подобного нет.